# Rename recordings that are stored on the server - Licode webRTC

Tags: javascript, chatroom, licode

I’m trying to save the recordings with the user name that is added to the room, I see that to rename the recordings I have to edit the variable recordingId in the erizoController.js file , but this leaves me a static name for all recordings and I want the recordings to be saved with the name of the user that is added to the room from index.html. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by equating the variable user.name of the listen function inside the variable var recordingId.
I hope it helps